# v-model and scoped slots not working?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a component:

```
<slot name="test" :name="name">
    <input type="text" v-model="name">
</slot>
```

The input is bound to name in data.

When I use the slot in the parent:

```
<div slot="test" slot-scope="props">
    <input type="text" v-model="props.name">
</div>
```

Data does not update on the child. It's not linked - why?

Comment: When you edit in the child it does not reflect in the parent OR when you edit in the parent it does not reflect in the child?

Comment: When you edit in parent, it does not effect the child.

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing is actually the parent's default `<input>`. So you understand what I mean, add some text to both, like:

```html
<slot name="test" :name="name">
    Default: <input type="text" v-model="name">
</slot>
```

```html
<div slot="test" slot-scope="props">
    Actual: <input type="text" v-model="props.name">
</div>
```

You'll see that what appears is the `default`.

Now, that happens because, it *seems* like a bug, when the slot prop has the same name as the parent's, the slot does not work.

## Workaround: rename the slot prop.

In the example below, I renamed it from `name` to `namex`. Notice the `v-model` in the default remains the same `name` because anything in the template refers to the props of *that* template (in other words, slot props, e.g. `namex`, will never be available in the parent default slot).

```html
<slot name="test" :namex="name">
    Default: <input type="text" v-model="name">
</slot>
```

```html
<div slot="test" slot-scope="props">
    Actual: <input type="text" v-model="props.namex">
</div>
```

Comment: I'm afraid this does not work. Even with the workaround, the model is not bound to the child component.

Comment: Do you see the `Actual:` text being rendered?

Comment: You should't modify the props passed to a slot, you should rather pass a callback as a slotProp as well, that will modify the data being passed as a slot prop, https://stackoverflow.com/a/61993508/8320709

Answer (score 1):

to use `v-model` in scoped slots, the value of `v-model` must be one level deeper:

```
Vue.component('render-props', {
  data: () => ({message: 'hello', obj: {msg: 'obj_msg'}}),
  template: `<div>
    <slot name="a" :message="message">
      default: {{message}}
      <input v-model="message"/>
    </slot>
    <slot name="b" :obj="obj">
      default: {{obj.msg}}
      <input v-model="obj.msg"/>
    </slot>
  </div>`
});
new Vue({
  el: "#root",
  template: `<div>
    <render-props>
      <template v-slot:a="props">
        actual: {{props.message}}
        <input v-model="props.message"/>
      </template>
      <template v-slot:b="props">
        actual: {{props.obj.msg}}
        <input v-model="props.obj.msg"/>
      </template>
    </render-props>
    <cus_2 />
  </div>`
});
```

Another easier case:

```
var Sub = Vue.extend({
  props: ['a', 'b'],
  template: `<div>
    <div>a : <input v-model="a" /></div>
    <div>b.txt : <input v-model="b.txt" /></div>
  </div>`
});

var Main = Vue.extend({
  components: { Sub },
  data() {
    return {
      a: 'aaa',
      b: { txt: 'bbb' },
      c: 'ccc',
    };
  },
  template: `<div>
    <Sub :a="a" :b="b" />
    <div>c : <input v-model="c" /></div>
    <ul>
      <li>a: {{a}}</li>
      <li>b.txt: {{b.txt}}</li>
      <li>c: {{c}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>`
});
new Main().$mount("#app");
```

`a` won't change, `b.txt and c` is ok.

Comment: This isn't the case here.

Answer (score 0):

> you are not supposed to modify the data you pass to a slot, pretty
>   much like a prop. You should pass a method instead to change tha
>   value. You can always pass an object and modify a property (like a
>   prop) but it's also not recommended

-from https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/9726

So I imagine something like

```
<template>
   <slot v-bind:value="value"></slot>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'FooBar',
  data() {
    value: '',
  },
  methods: {
    updateValue(e) {
      this.value = e.target.value;
    }
  },
};
</script>
```

Then when using the component `<FooBar>` instead of using `v-model`, you can use the passed scoped slot props, the method (`updateValue`), and actual prop that will be updated, `value`.

```
<FooBar v-slot="slotProps">
  <input type="text" :value="slotProps.value" @input="slotProps.updateValue" />
</Foobar>
```