# Vuejs v-model binding with a select box inside a slot

Tags: vue.js

Good afternoon,

I seem to have occured an issue with v-model binding in scoped slots.

I've tried to create a universal API form that would allow me to hook any URL to it, add any amount and any type of DOM elements inside a scoped slot and use data fetched from API accordingly.

So far I've managed to do the first part - fetch data and pass it to elements inside; the issue I'm having now is thanks to one-way data flow - selecting an option inside of `<select></select>` doesn't seem to update selectId accordingly - and I get it, that's the pattern it follows... now, how do I work around it?

## edit:

If I copy this select directly into the component (without passing via scoped slot) and replce props.* with just * (props.selectedId to selectedId) - it'll work flawlessly.

It only doesn't work because props are one-way.

```
<template>
    <form :action="action" :method="method">
        <slot :selectedId="selectedId" :results="results"></slot>
    </form>
</template>

<script>
    export default
    {
        props: ['action', 'method', 'url'],

        data: () =>
        ({
            results: [],
            selectedId: 0,
        }),

        created()
        {
            setTimeout(() =>
            {
                axios.get(this.url).then(response => (this.results = response.data))
            }, 500)
        },
    }
</script>
```

and HTML:

```
    <api-form action="/blog" method="POST" url="/api/v1/blog">
        <template slot-scope="props">
            <select class="form-control mb-3" v-model="props.selectedId">
                <option v-for="entry, i in props.results" :value="entry">@{{ entry.title }}</option>
            </select>
            <button class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
        </template>
    </api-form>
```

Comment: No idea how to make it work if you want to keep `results` and `selectedId` in your form component but if you fetched `results` and kept `selectedId` in your parent component, then passed them as props together with `action`, `method` and `url` it would work.

Comment: @dziraf yes, but selecting any option won't update selectId for other elements in the form, even if I use props.selectedId and not selectedId ;edit - I'll edit my main post a tiny bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gosh, I keep posting here and finding an answer afterwards.
4 hours of googling - nothing, then I post here and suddenly come up with a solution.

For anyone having the same issue, this is caused by the fact that all non-components, if you apply $emit to it, it'll be called from `<Root>`, meaning you have to edit your:

```
created()
{
    this.$on('update:selectedId', (value) =>
    {
        this.selectedId = value
    })
},
```

And change it to this:

```
created()
{
    this.$root.$on('update:selectedId', (value) =>
    {
        this.selectedId = value
    })
},
```

Answer (score -1):

You can pass a callback as a slot prop that will modify the data being passed also as a slot prop, here's an answer of mine on a similar question [v-model and scoped slots not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49512190/v-model-and-scoped-slots-not-working/61993508#61993508)